# iPhone wipe- "Verification Failed. There was a problem connecting to the server."

Tags: iphone, wifi

I wiped my iPhone 5s, but in the process of re-setting it up, it says "verification failed, there was a problem connecting to the server" after I tried submitting the two-factor identification code- even though the wifi is working. 
I tried to call apple support, but I have to have some "IBN"(?) number that I can only get to by going to settings, which I can't do because my iPhone isn't functioning yet. This number supposedly also comes with the packaging which I don't have anymore because I got the phone almost a year ago.

So, right now I'm stuck with a phone that won't log in, and I can't reach customer support about it. I've tried doing a hard reset with the lock and home button and retrying, but it won't work. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the phone to iTunes and set it up. That will remove any need to enter any data on the device or from the device. Once you do that one time, you can then set up the phone as you wish.